# JPA Spring boot attach a new Child to an existing entity in a ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I have discovered a In my opinion a strange behaver from jpa. First here is the a simplified version of my code ( If I missed something let me know)

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent")
Parent {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "parent_child_mapping",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Child_id"))
    private Set<Child> childs;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "child")
Child {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "keywords")
    private Set<Parent> parents;

    @Column(name = "name", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;

    public Child() {
       this.set = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public Child(String name, Parent p) {
         this();
         this.name = name;
         this.parents.add(p);
    }

    public Child(String name, Set<Parent> parents) {
         this();
         this.name = name;
         this.parents.addAll(parents);
    }
    
}
```

```
interface ChildRpo extends extends JpaRepository<Child , Long> { 
   Optional<Child> findByName(String name);
}
interface ParentRepo extends extends JpaRepository<Parent, Long> { 
   Optional<Parent> findByName(String name);
}
```

DB:

```
| Parent     |  | parent_child_mapping |  | Child       |
| id | name  |  | child_id | parent_id |  | id | name   |
|  1 | pa1   |  |     1    |     1     |  |  1 | child1 |
|  2 | pa2   |  |     2    |     1     |  |  2 | child2 |
```

```
Parent p1 = ParentRepo.findById(1).get() // Parent has Child 1 & 2 
Parent p2 = ParentRepo.findById(2).get() // Parent has no Childs
```

So now I get Data from a Rest Interface to add p2 a probably new child with a name

```
@Autowired
ChildRpo childRepo;
@Autowired
ParentRepo parentRepo;


@PostMapping("/example/{parentName}/{childName}")
public void add(@PathVar("parentName") String pName,
                @PathVar("childName") String cName) {
      // Here is the Problem I think 
      Parent p = parentRepo.findByName(pName).get();
      p.getChilds.add(new Child(cName,p);
      this.parentRepo.save(p);
}
```

Case1: pName = pa2  & cName = child3  (works as expected)

```
| Parent     |  | parent_child_mapping |  | Child       |
| id | name  |  | child_id | parent_id |  | id | name   |
|  1 | pa1   |  |     1    |     1     |  |  1 | child1 |
|  2 | pa2   |  |     2    |     1     |  |  2 | child2 |    
                |     3    |     2     |  |  3 | child3 |
```

Case2: pName = pa2  & cName = child1  (not quite what I expected) but how it is

```
| Parent     |  | parent_child_mapping |  | Child       |
| id | name  |  | child_id | parent_id |  | id | name   |
|  1 | pa1   |  |     1    |     1     |  |  1 | child1 |
|  2 | pa2   |  |     2    |     1     |  |  2 | child2 |    
                |     3    |     2     |  |  3 | child1 |
```

Case3: pName = pa2  & cName = child1  what I expected but how it isn't is

```
| Parent     |  | parent_child_mapping |  | Child       |
| id | name  |  | child_id | parent_id |  | id | name   |
|  1 | pa1   |  |     1    |     1     |  |  1 | child1 |
|  2 | pa2   |  |     2    |     1     |  |  2 | child2 |    
                |     1    |     2     |
```

I have to issues with this:

I thought that the unique attribute make a column unique so two strings with the same Content can't co exists in this row 'name' but It works. I would expect In case2 an exception.

And the second one:

How can I configuration it that it works like I wants them to work?
Do I have to load childOne's id? and Attach them to the new child1 entity?
I thought because the filed is unique that spring can decide:

The field isn't in the column so I add a new child.
The field is in the column so I will not create a new child instead I attach the parent to the old child with identical name. - but this isn't the way it works by default - is there a way that it works like described?

P.S:

Here is the domain Model from the current code:

```
Book -- oneToMany --> Page -- oneToMany --> Version -- ManyToOne --> Author
Book -- oneToMany --> Locations
..
```

How can I add 'Quick' a new Version to page with id = 5 and author with Id = 4 without loading all relationships.

EDIT: The Database is created by hibernate and here are the properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

Comment: Did you create the tables manually or was it created by hibernate? Your question is definitely missing details as `p.getChilds.add(new Child(cName);` will not do anything to database. If you have sample application with `Parent` and `Child` entity, you can give a link in the comments for https://friendpaste.com/ and can replicate it locally

Comment: you are right. I edit my post

Comment: That is not correct. You have to do bi-directional relation. `Child newChild = new Child(cName); p.getChilds.add(); newChild.setParent(p); this.parentRepo.save(p);`

Comment: Again you're right, I added the missing relationship as feature in the child's constructor. I could share them via frandpaste.com but If you want "working" entities I think you need all of them. This would be Seven entities and seven repos. I'll provide you son with the link

Comment: Here Is a Link to all classes from entities to controller: https://friendpaste.com/789VYe07DI172BpB0t8QtM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Unique attribute in a `@column` works only if the database was created automatically by JPA provider. Let the provider to recreate your db, if possible. You can do this from the properties.

   spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
2. You have to use a method in your jpa interface which finds (or not) a child using the name. Then check a result and create a new child, if it doesn't exist yet. This should work fine:

   ```
    Parent p = parentRepo.findByName(pName).get();
    Child newChild;
    Optional<Child> result = childRpo.findByName(cName);
    if(result != null) {
        newChild = result.get();
    }
    else {
        newChild = new Child(cName);
    }
    p.getChilds.add(newChild);
    newChild.getParents().add(p);
    parentRepo.save(p);
   ```

Comment: Yes this answer works like charm, but is on the slow side if you have a lot of childs or parents or other "heavy" (in terms of RAM-usage) relationships. Is there a way to archive exact the same result without loading the hole entity?

Comment: I think there is one way, buy you will have to read a little more about it, because i'm not not sure i can explain it. Since this is a many-to-many relationship you can use  `EmbeddedId` instead of usual ID generation, where you will save your childName and parent. This will probably solve your problem and will not have to load the child before saving it.

Comment: Well. @3asyPe answer is correct for the original problem you posted except `childRpo.save(newChild)` is not needed if you have cascade on parent. Now you don't have problem with functionality. Your comment here is a separate issue so may be raise a separate question. Alternatively check how to load your parent entity as proxy and save the child directly with proxy if your current issue is performance